# How to draw the pairwise marginal distribution for each pair of parameters in a grid using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bayesian

Assuming I have the posterior samples for each of the four parameters.  My question is how to plot the pairwise marginal distribution on a grid of 4*4=16 with ggplot2?

I would like to creat a plot like the picture below but instead of the scatter plot I will use a pairwise marginal distributions. Organized in the form of this kind of grid. [image]

I am wondering can ggmcmc package achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance, guys!!

Comment: In principle it is not too hard, you just need to put your values in a big long data table with the right id variable identifying the facet, and then facet plot it with the proper number of rows and columns. You could leave the diagonals blank and write some text there. If you had posted some example data I would give it a try. Or someone else would. No idea if ggmcmc would make it easier or harder.

Comment: `ggpairs` function from `GGally` package can do this

Comment: Thank you guys so much!! I see how to do it now from two perspectives. I will post some sample data and code below in case other people want to do it later.

Answer (score 3):

After getting help from the previous comments, I post the code below in case other people would like to do the same thing as me.

Below is a simple dataset I create for demonstration.This is the dataset "df" with four variables x, y, z, w. We want to get the pairwise joint kernel density estimation. One easy way I find is to use ggpairs from GGally package based on the comments by user20650. The codes are below: It will create the following plot: [image]

```
ggpairs(df,upper = list(continuous = "density"),
         lower = list(combo = "facetdensity"))

        x           y           z             w
1   0.49916998 -0.07439680  0.37731097  0.0927331640
2   0.25281542 -1.35130718  1.02680343  0.8462638556
3   0.50950876 -0.22157249 -0.71134553 -0.6137126948
4   0.28740609 -0.17460743 -0.62504812 -0.7658094835
5   0.28220492 -0.47080289 -0.33799637 -0.7032576540
6  -0.06108038 -0.49756810  0.49099505  0.5606988283
7   0.29427440 -1.14998030  0.89409384  0.5656682378
8  -0.37378096 -1.37798177  1.22424964  1.0976507702
9   0.24306941 -0.41519951  0.17502049 -0.1261603208
10  0.45686871 -0.08291032  0.75929106  0.7457002259
11 -0.16567173 -1.16855088  0.59439600  0.6410396945
12  0.22274809 -0.19632766  0.27193362  0.5532901113
13  1.25555629  0.24633499 -0.39836999 -0.5945792966
14  1.30440121  0.05595755  1.04363679  0.7379212885
15 -0.53739075 -0.01977930  0.22634275  0.4699563173
16  0.17740551 -0.56039760 -0.03278126 -0.0002523205
17  1.02873716  0.05929581 -0.74931661 -0.8830775310
18 -0.13417946 -0.60421101 -0.24532606 -0.1951831558
19  0.11552305 -0.14462104  0.28545703 -0.2527437818
20  0.71783902 -0.12285529  1.23488185  1.3224880574
```